# memory allocation of string literal strcpy

Tags: c, string

```
int main()
 {
  char *s;
  strcpy(s,"here");
  return 0;
  }
```

In the code above I guess the memory for the string literal is assigned in a global space.Which section does it actually go to and when ? Does the compiler go through and assign it in the program space ?? Also if i initalise another string with same string literal i.e ( `char *k = "here";` ) will it be pointing to the same memory location.
I am trying to think since I cannot free this location, do I run into any trouble if I have lot of string initialisations in my code. I guess the only thing I should be worried about is the compiler output being too big, since there is no run time memory allocation in this case?

Comment: The literal is allocated in `.rodata`. Or even not allocated at all as it is a short string and can fit into registers.But your code is invalid, anyway. Since `s` is not allocated at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exact location depends on the object file format ([PE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) vs. [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) vs. [COFF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COFF)) and any command-line options (some may allow string literals to be stored to a writable memory segment).  ELF will store it in the `.rodata` segment, which, as the name implies, is read-only.

Multiple instances of the same string literal *may* map to the same location, but it's not required AFAIK (I'm not aware of any compiler that creates multiple instances of the same literal, but my experience isn't that broad).

Things that are certain:

- Space for string literals is allocated at program startup (usually when the program is loaded into memory) and held until the program terminates;
- Attempting to modify the contents of a string literal invokes *undefined behavior* - your code *may* segfault, or it may work as intended, or it may reformat your hard drive, or it may trigger the zombie apocalypse.

Note that your code has a bug - you never assign a meaningful address to `s`, so the `strcpy` is essentially trying to write the string `"here"` to a random location, which again is undefined behavior.  You may have intended to write

```
s = "here";
```

which sets `s` to point to the literal.  If not, then `s` will either have to be an array large enough to hold the string:

```
char s[sizeof "here"]; // sizeof evaluated at compile time
```

or you'll have to allocate that space dynamically:

```
char *s = malloc( strlen( "here" ) + 1 );
if ( s )
  strcpy( s, "here" );
```